# Bash command to output to file using ProcessBuilder not working

Tags: java, bash, kotlin, command

So, I pretty much have the below code to write some text to a file using ProcessBuilder:

```
val requestStringBody = "{\"transfers\": [{\"amount\": 100, \"name\": \"Steve Rogers\", \"taxId\": \"330.731.970-10\",\"bankCode\": \"001\",\"branchCode\": \"1234\",\"accountNumber\": \"123456-0\"}]}"  

ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", ".\\git-bash.lnk", "-c", "echo -n \"$requestStringBody\" >> message.txt")
        .directory(File(My Path))
        .start()
        .waitFor()
```

I had to use the git-bash.lnk due to some windows issues.

I've tried the same command using a different variable as the requestBodyString and it works fine, which leads me to believe that that string has an issue with it, but I just cant figured out what.

EDIT: Solved it using File(fileName).writeText(fileContent).

Comment: You can use [Files.writeString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#writeString(java.nio.file.Path,java.lang.CharSequence,java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) to write text to a file.

Comment: @VGR I am using jdk8, so writeString is considered an unresolved reference

Comment: Then use [Files.write](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#write(java.nio.file.Path,java.lang.Iterable,java.nio.file.OpenOption...)).  For instance, `Files.write(Paths.get(myPath), Arrays.asList(requestStringBody));`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your actual problem probably comes from the fact that the string you are embedding in your command line contains double quotes and that messes up quoting (also quoting on Windows command line is a mess).

That being said, this looks like a very convoluted way to write text to a file... as @VGR wrote, you would be better off just using regular APIs to write to files in Java.

For instance using Kotlin 1.5's [Path.writeText](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io.path/java.nio.file.-path/write-text.html):

```kotlin
val requestStringBody = "{\"transfers\": [{\"amount\": 100, \"name\": \"Steve Rogers\", \"taxId\": \"330.731.970-10\",\"bankCode\": \"001\",\"branchCode\": \"1234\",\"accountNumber\": \"123456-0\"}]}"

Path("message.txt").writeText(requestStringBody)
```

Or with older versions:

```kotlin
File("message.txt").writeText(requestStringBody)
```